# How can a body be rotating when it's translating?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

How does a translating object (with constant velocity) seems to have a rotatory effect when viewed from a point not in its line of motion?

Comment: Note that movement in a straight line is also rotation - but with a non-constant radius.

Comment: @stafusa This can be misleading as rotation is absolute, while translation relative.

Comment: @my2cts You refer to fictitious forces? Since the OP explicitly cares only about how it looks like, I think we can restrict ourselves to kinematics.

Answer (score 2):

Your point of view is rotating, that is why.

Comment: Actually, if the point of view is rotating, following the body, its movement will appear 1D, won't it?

Comment: @stafusa Its distance varies and it has an apparent rotation. It is actually the observer who rotates.